# Qt + OS X + Bluetooth

Tags: qt, macos, bluetooth

I would like to create an app to send text alerts to bt devices on the neighbourhood but i'm finding incredible hard to get examples, APIs etc. is BT not so used?

Is it possible to use Qt to do that? (I think yes as the API of IObluetooth is C)

I've managed to import the IObluetooth.framework to Qt, but I cannot find any C/C++ examples, api or help. any help here?

thanks

Comment: Could you please explain how did you import IOBluetooth framework to QT.

Answer (score 0):

QtMobility has a  connectivity Module that supports BlueTooth transfers but currently only on Symbian and Linux.
    http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/connectivity-api.html

You either have to search for a 3rd party library or use Native Code to achieve this.

Comment: I would like to use the Bluetooth.framework from osx that works with c and c++ as far as i know but i can't find any documentation...